# Telerik ASP .NET MVC Grid - adding custom delete button

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, telerik

Currently using Telerik ASP .NET MVC Controls version 2011.2.712

Hello all, I am trying to implement a custom delete button. The reason for this is I have some other custom commands on my grid row and I would like to keep them all together. I would also like to point out that the grid is embedded within a tab on a larger display that includes other updatable grids. My grid definition is as follows:

```
Html.Telerik().Grid<CommentDto>()
    .Name("ReportCommentGrid")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(o => o.Id))
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Select("SelectReportComment", "DebtRisk", new { id = Model.ReportCommentId })
        .Delete("DeleteReportComment", "DebtRisk")
        )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.AssetGroupTypeCode).Title("Group").Width("10em").ReadOnly();
        columns.Bound(o => o.Text).Title("Comment").Width("25em").ReadOnly();
        columns.Bound(o => o.Id).ClientTemplate(
                "<# if(CreatedBy != null) { #>"
                + "<a class='t-button' href='#' onclick=\"LaunchCommentEditWindow('/DebtRisk/EditReportComment/<#= Id #>')\">Edit</a>"
                + "<a class=\"t-button t-grid-delete\" href=\"#\">Delete</a>"
                + "<# }  #>"
        ).Width("15em").Title("Related Data").ReadOnly(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "t-last"})
    })
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("ReportCommentGrid_onRowDataBound"))
    .Footer(false)
    .Render();
```

I have the following javascript on the "ReportCommentGrid_onRowDataBound" event handler:

```
function  ReportCommentGrid_onRowDataBound(e)
{
    $(e.row).find('.t-grid-delete').click(function (ev)
    {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();
        var grid = $("#ReportCommentGrid").data('tGrid');
        grid.deleteRow($(this).closest('tr'));

        return false;
    });
}
```

When I run the code and select the "Delete" button I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error on the "grid.deleteRow". Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never figured out how to implement a "Command" button outside the command column. I was able to use the new custom command available in the 2011 Q3 release (currently beta) to implement my custom edit button as a custom command.

This custom edit button launches a pop-up window containing an edit form for the data on the grid row. I was not able to make the built-in popup edit work for me. Here the code below.

**Custom Edit button definition:**

```
commands.Custom("EditReportComment")
.Text("Edit")
.Ajax(true)
.Action("EditReportComment","DebtRisk")
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class="edit-report-comment" })
.DataRouteValues(route => route.Add(o => o.Id).RouteKey("id"))
;
```

**Client event needed to attach row specific on-click event to edit button:**

```
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("ReportCommentGrid_onRowDataBound"))
```

On-Click wireup: (pulls href from button definition for window URL)

```
function ReportCommentGrid_onRowDataBound(e)
{
    var editLink = $(e.row).find('.edit-report-comment')
    editLink.click(function (ev)
    {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();
        LaunchCommentEditWindow(editLink.attr("href"));
        return false;
    });
}
```

**Pop-Up Window Launcher:**

```
function LaunchCommentEditWindow(editUrl)
{
    var newWindow = $("<div id='EditReportComment'></div>").tWindow(
        {
        title: 'Edit Comment',
        contentUrl: editUrl,
        modal: true,
        resizeable: false,
        scrollable: false,
        width: 550,
        height: 200,
        onClose: function (e){ e.preventDefault(); newWindow.data('tWindow').destroy(); }
    });
    newWindow.data("tWindow").center().open();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Q3 2011 beta custom column command option is available. See the demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc-beta/grid/customcolumncommand)

```
Html.Telerik().Grid<UserManagement.Models.vmmodel>()
    .Name("setupEmployees")
   .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "float:left;" })
        .Columns(colums =>
        {                
                colums.Command(commands => commands
                .Custom("Edit")
                .Text("Edit")
                .SendState(false)  
                .DataRouteValues(route =>
                {                        
                    route.Add(o => o.EmployeeID).RouteKey("orderID");                        
                })                    
                  .Ajax(true)
                .Action("actionresult", "mycontroller"));

                colums.Command(commands => commands
                    .Custom("delete")
                    .Text("delete")
                    .SendState(false)
                    .DataRouteValues(route =>
                    {
                        route.Add(o => o.EmployeeID).RouteKey("orderID");
                    })
                      .Ajax(true)
                    .Action("actionresult", "mycontroller"));

            colums.Bound(o => o.EmployeeID);
            colums.Bound(o => o.EmployeeID);

        })

    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()        
    .PrefixUrlParameters(false)

    .Render();
```

%>

Comment: I've seen that release but I wasn't sure if it was one of the free releases available. Also, I just ran the demo and received this javascript error when clicking the "Customer Deatils" button: "'console' is undefined". Looks like there may still be some issues to work out.

Comment: Yes it is free and full version will be available in early November. I ran the sample and it is working fine. just add the code in view as shown in demo page

Comment: The custom commands still have to be defined within the "command" column. I wanted to create a "delete" command outside the command column. I a was however able to move my "Edit" button into the "Commands" column using the new custom command feature. See my answer below.

Comment: I am assuming that you want your own edit and delete button if that is the case you don't need to make grid editable. See my updated answer

Comment: Actually your example is not what I was looking for. Your original answer, however, pointed me to the 2011 Q3 beta which allowed me to implement my custom edit command within the "columns.Command". See the example in my answer below. Now both commands display within the same column on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't add the commands the telerik grid wont add the javascript that supports that action.  would your delete link not just need to go to an action on your controller anyway?  why use javascript at all?

Comment: The grid is embedded in a tab which is part of a larger display. I would prefer to update the grid using Ajax. The javascript emulates the wire-up of the delete button click event when the grid data is loaded.